# Были ли прецеденты, чтобы триумфальную арку называли аркой триумфа?

Tags: выбор-слов, синонимы

> Нельзя не упомянуть и старания пятнадцати понтификов, каждый из
>   которых тем или иным способом участвовал в создании легенды Рима. И
>   кто-то из них принимал или отвергал проекты; кто-то, не вникая в
>   вопросы эстетики, был занят чисто техническими задачами: приводил в
>   порядок акведук Аква Вирго; кто-то вводил специальные налоги, дабы
>   ускорить завершение строительства... Но каждый из них надеялся
>   начертать своё имя на арке триумфа фонтана Треви.

Comment: Я бы советовал подумать, насколько уместно здесь двоеточие. Я бы поставил тире, на худой конец - скобки. Другой вариант: добавить слово "например" (с запятыми, конечно)

Comment: Спасибо, это я прозевала, внося правку: беру тире!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Триумфальная арка**  ― архитектурный памятник, представляющий собой большую торжественно оформленную арку. (Триумф ― выдающийся, блестящий успех, победа, торжество.) Это сочетание может иметь **нарицательный смысл** (и триумфальную арку можно назвать аркой триумфа), а может быть **именем собственным**, если относится к конкретному памятнику.

В Петербурге есть Нарвские триумфальные ворота, в одной статье они названы [Аркой триумфа](http://studydoc.ru/doc/2620854/arka-triumfa).

Что касается фонтана Треви, то он  был пристроен к фасаду старинного палаццо герцогов Поли. Фонтан Треви и палаццо Поли воспринимаются как единый, целостный архитектурный ансамбль. Из центральной ниши дворца, **своеобразной триумфальной арки,** будто выезжает Нептун на запряженной морскими коньками раковине-колеснице. [Экскурсии в Италии - Фонтан Треви | warps.ru](http://warps.ru/%D0%98%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%8F/%D0%AD%D0%BA%D1%81%D0%BA%D1%83%D1%80%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%B8-%D0%A4%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD_%D0%A2%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%B8.html)

Поэтому триумфальная арка фонтана Треви ― это,  скорее всего, нарицательное название, и ее вполне можно назвать **аркой триумфа.**